# Python (Autodesk Revit Dynamo) - Cannot find issue that unexpected token '<newline>' error refers to

Tags: python, list, duplicates, autodesk

UPDATE: I have added the missing variable to the elif line. Now I am receiving an error for invalid syntax. TIA.

I am a bit lacking in programming experience, so if this is an amateur question, please excuse me.

I am currently working in Autodesk Revit Dynamo to create a python script node that takes a list as an input, identifies duplicate items, and sorts them into multiple lists.

(For example, if I have a list of values such as (1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,5). I should get one list that is (1,1,1), one that is (2,2), one that is (3), one that is (4,4,4,4), and one that is (5). Making a total of 5 lists because I have 5 unique values.)

Because the input data could vary in the number of total items as well as the number of unique items (and therefore the number of lists to output), I am trying to make the code dynamic.

Currently when I try the code I receive the following error:

**Warning: IronPythonEvaluator.EvaluateIronPythonScript operation failed. 
unexpected token '< newline >'**

I believe this is due to a syntax error, but please correct me if I am wrong. I cannot seem to find what the error is referring to. Can somebody please help me identify and correct the issue? Thanks in advance.

```
import clr

input = IN[0]
output = []

listcount = []

n = 1
n = str(n)
listn = "list" + n
vars()['listn'] = []

def newlist(n):
    n = n + 1
    n = str(n)
    listn = "list" + n
    vars()['listn'] = []
    return

def listsofduplicates(input):
    list1.append([0])
    output.append(list1)
    listcount.append(n)
    input = input - [0]

    for x in input:
        if x in list1:
            list1.append(x)
        elif x not in list1:
            for n in listcount:
                if x in output(n):
                    list"n".append(x)
        else:
            newlist = newlist(n)
            newlist.append(x)
            listcount.append(n)
            output.append(newlist)
    return

listsofduplicates(input)

#Assign your output to the OUT variable.
OUT = output
```

Comment: `elif x not in:` something is missing here...

Comment: Thank you! I cannot believe I missed that, it should've been obvious.